# Simultaneous eigenkets of two Hermitian and anti-commutative linear operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I'm working through the problems at the end of the first chapter of the third edition of Sakurai and Napolitano's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, and I've hit a snag with problem 1.18:

> "Two Hermitian operators anticommute:
> \begin{equation*}
> \left\{A,B\right\} = AB + BA = 0.
> \end{equation*}
> Is it possible to have a simultaneous (that is, common) eigenket of $A$ and $B$? Prove or illustrate your assertion."

It is clear to me that one can show *if* a simultaneous eigenket exists, then the eigenvalue corresponding to such an eigenket must be zero for at least one of $A$ or $B$.

I'm not sure, though, the right way to go about showing that such a simultaneous eigenket exists in the first place. My instinct is that the answer is yes, there can be a simultaneous eigenket, and the way I thought to illustrate it is by trying to find a pair of anticommuting matrices that share an eigenvector, but before I set about the search for an example, I wanted to see if my intuition is correct. If it isn't, I'd appreciate any guidance towards the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would be two 3 by 3 matrices, with each 2 by 2 top left block being a distinct Pauli matrix. If every other entry in both matrices is zero, except for one of the matrices having the bottom right entry as a nonzero real number, then these two matrices satisfy all the conditions. The common eigenket is $(0,0,1)^T$. I think this example gives a clue as how to formulate the most general solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems like it might even work if, outside of the Pauli matrix blocks, all the entries are zero (i.e., no need for the nonzero entry in the bottom-right corner of one of the matrices). At any rate, you've given me the example I needed, and some idea of why the problem was included in the text at all.